# How to check in Django if a maximum of db entries is reached and if so roll back?

Tags: django

I want to check if a maximum of db entries is reached (=booked out). With Django 1.5 I used something like this:

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if MyModel.objects.all().count() > max:
        raise ValidationError('It was just fully booked.')
```

I don't know if that's nonsense. Anyway I can't execute queries (`MyModel.objects.count()`) within the new `transaction.atomic` block. (I get the error `TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.`. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) say: *If you attempt to run database queries before the rollback happens, Django will raise a TransactionManagementError.*)

What is the best practice to reach my goal? Is there a particular term for that issue?

(Background: I thought when several users create `MyModel` objects at the same time when `max` is almost reached I had more entries in the db than `max` allowed. Therefore I thought it was a good idea to check (also) after saving.)

Comment: Just letting you know: You don't have to call `all()` before `count()` to count all model objects, simply do `MyModel.objects.count()`

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't execute queries"? What happens when you do? Also, this scheme isn't going to do what you want under default transaction isolation levels. It should work if you use `SERIALIZABLE`, but you need to check your database-specific documentation. You could also acquire a table lock.

Comment: You don't need @transaction.commit_on_success on the save method; you are also saving first before checking, so its not doing what you think.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry. I updated my question (but the code that produced the error is more complex). I quickly read the PostgreSQL docs about serialisable… It will take me a while to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a few ways of accomplishing what you want. It depends on how your database is used.

If there is only one single-threaded web server accessing your database, the above approach will work. You may be better off leaving the `save` method alone, and instead override the `clean` method on the Model:

```
def clean(self):
    # make sure that user and group are in the same company
    if MyModel.objects.all().count() > max:
        raise ValidationError(
            'All booked out'
        )
```

However, if it possible for multiple servers or threads to run the above code, you will get into trouble. Let's say that your max is 10. Your DB currently contains 9 entries. Two servers run the above code at the same time, and it passes, as in each case, max has not been reached. Each writes to the database, and now you have 11 entries.

There is a way around that. You can create a new model, called EntryCount. Have it contain only one row, which contains a single numeric value. This is the count of entries. There will also be a DB constraint on this column which says that its maximum value is 10. Your save method would need to be overridden to increment this number. If you try to make the number higher than 10, it will raise an error.

The reason for this alternate approach is that count(*) works in subtly strange ways. There are things like isolation levels which may make things look different from different DB connections.

Comment: Your scenario about the issue with concurrent reads is correct. However, your solution will present the same problem *unless* the code is designed to get a *write* lock when it *reads* `EntryCount`'s single row. This is typically done with `select_for_update`. And I disagree with the notion that `count(*)` "works in subtly strange ways". There's nothing subtle or strange about the way it works.

Comment: @Louis That means it was a good solution to subclass my save method with
`try: counter = EntryCount.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=pk);
counter.count += 1;
counter.save();
super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs);
except:...`

Comment: @Louis By subtly strange, I understand that I am being vague. I have an apprehension to `count(*)` based on experience with various DBMSes. Different ones require different locks on a table before getting a full count. I do not remember the details, but I would not depend on `count(*)` behavior in a multi-threaded environment unless I did concrete research and testing with the particular DBMS I am using. Sure, the behavior is well-defined in each DBMS. However, I have found it to work in ways which were surprising, in subtly strange ways :)

Comment: I accept this answer together with the first comment of Louis. Thanks to both!